Why did I get an invalid handle (not zero) when I called the dlopen() function on CentOS?
I attempted to install a seccomp BPF filter for a running Tomcat process. After attaching gdb to the process, I invoked the dlopen function to load a shared library (.so file), which returned a handle.The handle was a integer, not zero. However, when I used the gdb x command to inspect the memory contents of the handle, the gdb prompt showed an error: Cannot access memory at address. Subsequently, I tried calling dlsym using the handle as a parameter, but gdb was terminated because a SIGSEGV signal occurred.
Here is the illustration:
(gdb) set $handle=dlopen("/opt/seccompfilter.so",1)
(gdb) x $handle
0xffffffffaaef8730:     Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffaaef8730
(gdb) call dlsym((void *)$handle, "install_filter")
[Thread 0x7f6250aed700 (LWP 2069) exited]
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_dl_lookup_symbol_x (undef_name=0x5636aaef81d0 "install_filter", 
undef_map=0xffffffffaaef8730, ref=0x7ffe774956a0, 
symbol_scope=0xffffffffaaef8ab8, version=0x0, type_class=0,
flags=2, skip_map=0x0) at dl-lookup.c:733
733         while ((*scope)->r_list[i] != skip_map)
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called 
from GDB.
GDB remains in the frame where the signal was received.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal on".
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(__dlsym) will be abandoned.
When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.

I'm trying to understand what went wrong. Here is the environment I was working with:
CentOS 7 kernel-3.10.0-1160.90.1.el7.x86_64
gdb 7.6.1-120.el7
glibc 2.17

Interestingly, when I performed the same steps on Ubuntu 20.04, everything worked successfully.
What's the problem?
I have tried calling the dlopen function to load the libc.so.6 shared library, and it got the same result.

Maybe you could show exactly what you did when you got the SIGSEGV?

Are you sure that the process was terminated by a SIGSEGV and not GDB itself?

gdb 7.6.1 is more than 10 years old. A more recent one would probably have told you dlopen has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type. In that case you probably have to do something like: set $handle=((void*(*)(char*,int))dlopen)("/opt/seccompfilter.so",1)

@ssbssa I tried your approach, but it got the same result. The critical problem is why the handle can't be accessed in memory.


I'm trying to understand what went wrong.

The $handle value 0xffffffffaaef8730 is wrong. On x86_64 user-space memory addresses (and the handle returned by dlopen actually points to struct link_map) are in the range [0x1000 - 0x7fffffffffff], and anything in the 0xffffffff........ range can only be a kernel address.
Now, why did this happen?
Most likely GDB mis-interpreted the return type of dlopen in the $rax as int32_t, and sign-extended it to int64_t.
A dlopen return might look something like 0x00007ffffaaef8730, and if you do the mis-interpretation above, you would get exactly the value you actually got:
(gdb) p/x (long)(int)0x00007ffffaaef8730
$1 = 0xffffffffaaef8730

The ancient version of GDB you are using may have a bug in it. The other possibility -- that GDB doesn't know the actual dlopen return type -- seems unlikely given that it does have debug info for GLIBC.
You may wish to set a breakpoint on dlopen, use finish to return from it, and examine the $rax directly.
